# Swift Firestore calling data - Values do not exist after creating account

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

After I create an account with Firebase I save values to Firestore. I want to take this data and save it to realtime database after a user creates an account. After testing I noticed that after the account is created the values do not exist even though the values are saved into Firestore. After I log out of the account and log back in the values are now accessible. What could be the issue?

**Swift Firebase Firestore calls for data**

```
func callCustomerStripeInfo() {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("stripe_customers").document(customerUid!).getDocument { (snapshot, err) in
           if let err = err {
               print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
           } else {
            let stripeInfo = snapshot?.data()
            let stripe_customer_id = stripeInfo!["customer_id"] as! String
            let stripe_setup_secret = stripeInfo!["setup_secret"] as! String
            print(stripe_customer_id)
            print(stripe_setup_secret)
            Database.database().reference().child("user_profiles").child(self.customerUid!).updateChildValues(["customer_id":stripe_customer_id, "setup_secret":stripe_setup_secret])
           }
     }
}
```

**Firestore rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read;
  allow write: if false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you try to write to the Realtime Database with hard-coded values, without first reading them from Firestore, do you have the same problem?

Comment: The question is a little vague - what does *the values do not exist even though the values are saved* mean? Specifically, what doesn't exist and how do you know they don't exist? Also, and this is off topic, but why are you using two different databases to store the same data? Why not just stick with Firestore (or the RTDB to simplify things?

Comment: I had moved my Firestore call to a more fitting view than the first view you are presented in that app after sign-up and the values are called properly. I am using RTDB and Firestore because RTDB has all data and I am using Firestore just for stripe.

Comment: Does that mean you've solved the issue? If not, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get real time updates with Cloud Firestore, you will have to use the `addSnapshotListener()` method. Check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) for further information.